# Check download progress of 'wget' after starting it in background mode

Tags: ssh, downloads, wget

I had to download multiple files using wget over a SSH Server, so I pasted the links in a file named 'link'.

I used this command to download the files in background even after disconnecting from the server:

```
wget -bqc -i link
```

It gave output as:

```
Continuing in background, pid 1353.
```

Now how do I check the download progress of the files, as the process is running in background..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it with `-o` option and check the log for the progress:

```
wget -o log http://file
```

Comment: alternatively you can bring your process back, check this: https://superuser.com/questions/732503/redirect-stdout-stderr-of-a-background-job-from-console-to-a-log-file

Answer (score 1):

First you need to locate the file that you downloaded, then use the command:

```
du /path/to/file
```

substitute `path/to/file` with the path to the file name (ex. `/home/user/Downloads/image.jpg`)

It will show you the size of the file. You can run it more than once to see if the file size changes.